# how to construct complex user permissions set

Tags: database-design, permissions

My question isn't code oriented, instead it is about design/architecture. I'm building a site with an extremely complex set of user permissions, and I'm hoping to poll the stack overflow genius pool, see if anyone has any brilliant ideas or suggestions :-D.

I am handling user authorization/tracking with tank auth for codeigniter, so basic user validation isn't the issue I'm inquiring about. Also, as I said, the project is going to need to handle a very complex set of user permissions, and simply user role assignment won't cut it. Let me try to explain the site behavior as best as possible for clarity.

The project has a kind of social networking basis. A user will be able to create a group, and other members will be able to join that group. Furthermore, users can create and/or belong to more than one group, with no size limitations. So assuming the site becomes popular (here's hoping...) it will be possible for there to exist 500 groups, one of which may have 5 members, and another group may have 1000; each of those 1000 belonging to 2,3 or 20 other groups. The term many-to-many doesn't quite seem sufficient.

So my plan is to track these permissions through the database. However, if I try to track a group's members in it's data record I end up with one of two problems. Listing the users belonging to a group in a single cell as a string would make updating/accessing a the data a nightmare. For example, if a user unregisters for the site the db would have to iterate through every single group's  permission field to remove that user. On the other hand, if I track each user's id #'s in an individual cell of that record the data can be easily selected/deleted, but I end up with the problem of an unmanageable number of fields. Let's say I set aside 100 fields to store user id's in. If a group needs 101 everything breaks. This also has the problem of most groups containing a whole lot of null fields.

Currently the best approach I have been able to think up is a separate table with three fields, PERMISSION_ID, (an essentially useless primary key) GROUP_ID, and USER_ID; such that each permission is an individual record. It bothers me, and goes against what I've learned about databases, to have a useless (as good as non-existent) primary key, but this is the best method I've been able to think up. At least this way the table can be searched and updated easily by either group id or user id.

Before I started to actually implement this solution, I thought I would ask to see if there was something I've overlooked or if anyone had a better approach. I am totally willing to be humbled by another's genius. Sorry that this question is so verbose, I wanted to try and clearly illustrate the situation. Thank you for taking the time to read it, and any advice you may have.

Comment: `WALL OF TEXT CRITS FOR 9999`